# Building Grid with Flexbox - How to setup multiple Items / Divs beside and down each other?

Tags: html, css, css-float, flexbox

i want to build my Grid with Flexbox and get stucked a little bit.
How can a set a Box and towards on right Side multiple Boxes with half the Size of Box 1. Box 2-5 should then float towards Box 1.

[image: Scribble]

See in Scribble what i mean and how it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
}
.left, .right {
  flex: 1; /* Distribute width equally */
}
.right {
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Allow multiple lines */
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Center content vertically */
  justify-content: center; /* Center content horizontally */
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  margin: 1px 2px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left box">
    Box 1
  </div>
  <div class="right wrapper">
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```